# Compiling a tex file with Texmaker changes the "date modified" meta-information

Tags: texmaker

I have noticed that compiling a tex file with Texmaker changes its "date modified" meta-information. Why, and is there any way to avoid it? (git considers the file as having changed).

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask the author of the program. In my experience he is willing to reply.

Comment: Out of curiosity as I don't use Texmaker: if `git` considers the file has changed, then something inside it has changed, not only its modification date as a file. Thus the `meta-information` is something in the tex source ? or you are referring to the `pdf` output ?

Comment: @jfbu I thought so too, but it seems not: [GitHub Desktop: “This file is empty”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34559255/395857)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'll wait a bit before emailing him in case someone here knows.

Comment: Ok. Or submit a bug or feature request so that others can find it if they have the same question.

Comment: I use `git` only locally on the command line not via GitHub Desktop. I never saw a (text) file being reported as changed by git status when only the modification time has been changed (via touch for example). Hence I am not sur about what you mean by `file metadata`. Perhaps something TeXmaker adds to the tex file ?